# Getting the values of a dictionary contained in a list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Having a list like:

```
my_list = [
  [{'score':9, 'name':'Jack'}],
  [{'score':3, 'name':'Danielle'}]
]
```

I am trying to iterate through this list but can't figure out how to access the values.

```
for listing in my_list:
  print(listing['score'])
```

The above does not work. Which I understand as I seem to be working on a dictionary that is still inside the second list. However, I am having trouble finding out the correct way to do get access.

Comment: the syntax is incorrect.

Comment: Dictionaries are constructed with `{...}` rather than `[...]`.

Comment: @VishalSingh I fixed it. Tried to make a minimal example of the problem and I guess my head is in space somewhere atm. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong syntax for [python dictionaries](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp).

Python dictionaries are declared between `{...}`.

Your list should look like:

```
my_list = [
  {'score':9, 'name':'Jack'},
  {'score':3, 'name':'Danielle'}
]
```

**EDIT:**
In your edit you have a list within a list. Try

```
for listing in my_list:
  print(listing[0]['score'])
```

Comment: My example was incorrect. I messed up producing a minimal example. Fixed that.

Answer (score 5):

You can try this by matching exact the signature of the inner elements. This is called [`tuple unpacking`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/)

```
my_list = [
  [{'score':9, 'name':'Jack'}],
  [{'score':3, 'name':'Danielle'}]
]
for [listing] in my_list:
    print(listing['score'])
# 9
# 3
```

Answer (score 1):

What are you creating is a 2D List, you need Dictionaries inside that

```
my_list = [
  {'score':9, 'name':'Jack'},
  {'score':3, 'name':'Danielle'}
]
for listing in my_list:
  print(listing['score'])
```

Comment: My example was incorrect. I messed up producing a minimal example. Fixed that.

Answer (score 1):

You need 2 loops, one for the outer list, and one for the inner list:

```
my_list = [
     [{'score':9, 'name':'Jack'}],
     [{'score':3, 'name':'Danielle'}]
]

for sublist in my_list:
     for dct in sublist:
          print(dct['score'])
# 9
# 3
```

You can also use [nested list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html):

```
print([dct['score'] for sublist in my_list for dct in sublist])
# [9, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the items inside your list with `{}` rather than `[]`.

```
my_list = [
  {'score':9, 'name':'Jack'},
  {'score':3, 'name':'Danielle'}
]
```

`[]` will create a `list`, while `{}` will create a `dict`.

Comment: My example was incorrect. I messed up producing a minimal example. Fixed that.